# csv.writer writing all contents to one cell

Tags: python, excel, csv, python-3.x

**EDIT**: Solved thanks to @ayhan. If you are from Poland use semicolon instead of comma as a separator.

I have a list of lists that looks like this:

```
list = [['edytor poranka PN', '1/04/2016', '15:00'], ['edytor PN 2', '2/04/2016', '08:30'], ['edytor PN noc', '3/04/2016', '22:00']]
```

`csv.writer` writes each list into one cell instead to 3 separate ones.

My code looks like this:

```
with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerows(list)
```

I've also tried this method:

```
for i in list:
    writer.writerow(i)
```

And it also doesn't  work. My other issue is that each row is separated by an extra empty row and I don't know how to get rid of it. I know there has been similar questions but no solution is working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Slayer's code worked for me here is the US, but if I changed my Windows Region and Language settings to Poland it doesn't and I *was* finally able to reproduce your problem.

According to @ayhan this is because of a bug in Excel where it expects `;` to be the delimiter when reading and saving csv files in locales where `,` is used as the decimal separator (decimal mark) such as it is in Poland (and most of the rest of the world).

Probably the easiest work-around is just specify the delimiter Excel expects in your region when you create the `csv.writer` object, as shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv

list_of_lists = [['edytor poranka PN', '1/04/2016', '15:00'],
                 ['edytor PN 2', '2/04/2016', '08:30'],
                 ['edytor PN noc', '3/04/2016', '22:00']]

with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    for sublist in list_of_lists:
        writer.writerow(sublist)
```

Contents of `file.csv` after running the script:

```
edytor poranka PN;1/04/2016;15:00
edytor PN 2;2/04/2016;08:30
edytor PN noc;3/04/2016;22:00
```

Afterwards, if I open it in Microsoft Excel 2013, with my Windows Format and Location set to "Poland" in the Windows Region and Language control panel, I see the following (which is now correct):

[image: screenshot of file after opening it in excel 2013]

**Update**

A way of doing it dynamically would be to have the script determine what delimiter to use based on the current locale settings and pick something different if there's a conflict — although hardcoding `;` should work any place that doesn't use it as the decimal mark (and I'm not aware of one that does).

Since we now know what was causing the issue, I would also take out the `for` loop Slayer introduced and go back to the version of your code that used `writerows()`.

```
import csv
import locale

# Chose an Excel compatible csv delimiter.
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
DELIMITER = ';' if locale.localeconv()['decimal_point'] == ',' else ','

list_of_lists = [['edytor poranka PN', '1/04/2016', '15:00'],
                 ['edytor PN 2', '2/04/2016', '08:30'],
                 ['edytor PN noc', '3/04/2016', '22:00']]

with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=DELIMITER)
    writer.writerows(list_of_lists)
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. I am using excel 2010. Could this be an issue?

Comment: Regional settings of your operating system may be an issue. If the default delimiter is not comma, Excel will show all of them in the same cell.

Comment: I suppose that you using Excel 2010 could be the reason (but doubt it). The default delimiter for csv files is always commas according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters) (see `Dialect.delimiter`) and isn't affected by your operating system's regional settings.

Comment: @Bolesław: Does the file look OK (like above in the answer) if you open it in a text editor?

Comment: The one I mentioned is an Excel issue. In some countries comma is used as the decimal separator. In that case Excel saves csv files using a different separator (for example `;`). It also expects the same separator while reading.

Comment: @ayhan: That must be it. I just changed both my Format and Location settings in the Windows Region and Language control panel to "Polish (Poland)" and "Poland" respectively and then the OP's problem occurs (in Excel 2013).

Comment: @ayhan You are the Man (or Woman). This was actually the case. Works as intended when i separete them with semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the newline to prevent the extra row from being added on each iteration. Also naming your variable `list` is a bad idea, since it's a built in type.

```
with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for a_list in lists:
        writer.writerow(a_list)
```

Comment: Good suggestions, but the OP said they already tried `for i in list:`, `writer.writerow(i)`.

Comment: The OP said they had tried this but each row was seperated by a blank row. Which is why it wasn't working. The new rows are added because of not setting the `newline` parameter

Comment: Thanks. newline helped with blank rows but it is still all in one cell.

Comment: @Bolesław: I think you should add a few lines  to your question showing some or all of the actual contents of the variable named `list`.

Comment: @martineau list = [['edytor poranka PN', '1/04/2016', '15:00'], ['edytor PN 2', '2/04/2016', '08:30'], ['edytor PN noc', '3/04/2016', '22:00']]

Comment: FWIW, the code in this answer works for me with your sample data.

Comment: Iteresting. Do you have any idea why it is not working for me?

Comment: How are you determining that each sublist has been written into one cell?

Comment: The contents of the output .csv file after running this code with the sample data: `edytor poranka PN,1/04/2016,15:00`, `edytor PN 2,2/04/2016,08:30`, `edytor PN noc,3/04/2016,22:00`

Comment: simply by opening the excel file. It looks like this:http://imgur.com/pwQXLmh. I have copied Slayer's code, changed variables but still no effect

Comment: So maybe my list is worng. I want each value separated by coma to be in separate cell. So there would be 3 columns in total

Comment: Your list seems OK to me. When I open the file with Excel 2013, see [imgur.com/HztMHxi](http://imgur.com/HztMHxi) it also looks OK.

Comment: I'll post it in an answer.