# Writing a dictionary into a CSV file with both items next to each other instead of below each other

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, writer

I think this is a simple question but I have been looking for so long and havent found a solution to my problem.

So I have a function that is being called multiple times (objective function in my code). Each time a set of parameters are choosen and the time of running my code is calculated. Now I want to write the set of parameters together with their belonging time value into a CSV file.

The parameters are stored in a list and the value is a simple float. Toegether I store them in a dictionary. Now when I write them to the CSV file, I want the parameters to be stored in one cell and the belonging time value in the cell next to it. It will make it easy for me to sort by value and find the parameters that led to the highest time values. (Ideally the different parameters are stored in seperated cells as well but that is not that important).

**So I what I want would look like this:**

| Parameters | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 1,2,3 | 1 s |
| 10,20,30 | 2 s |

**Or even better would be:**

| Parameter A | Parameter B | Parameter c | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1s |
| 10 | 20 | 30 | 2s |

**What I have now is this:**

| Parameters | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 1,2,3 | - |
| - | - |
| 1s | - |
| - | - |
| 10,20,30 | - |
| - | - |
| 2s | - |
| - | - |

My code now is looking like this:

```
def objective(trial):

    start = time.perf_counter

    # Here some Parameters are choosen

    # Here happens some calculations

    end = time.perf_counter()
    duration = end-start

    params_csv = [batch_size, model_type, n_layers, n_hidden, weight_decay, dropout, lr,
                  eta_min, T0, T_mult]
    dict_csv = {"Params": params_csv, "Time": duration}

    out_file = 'optuna_time_trials_9.csv'
    of_connection = open(out_file, 'a')
    writer_params = csv.writer(of_connection)

    for key, value in dict_csv.items():
        writer_params.writerow([key, value])
    return foo

study = optuna.create_study(direction='minimize', study_name='Optuna_Parameter_Time_11',
                            storage='sqlite:///example2.db', load_if_exists=True )
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=15)
```

Comment: I don't see how you're getting that output from the code you posted.

Comment: It should just create two rows. One will have the word `Params` in column 1, the next will have `Time` in column 1.

Comment: So I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520040/csv-writer-writing-all-contents-to-one-cell

Answer (score 0):

You should just use the list of parameters as the list to write with `writerow()`. And add `duration` to the end of the list to add that column to the CSV.

There's no need for the dictionary.

```
def objective(trial):

    start = time.perf_counter
    
    # Here some Parameters are choosen 

    # Here happens some calculations

    end = time.perf_counter()

    duration = end-start

    out_file = 'optuna_time_trials_9.csv'
    with open(out_file, 'a') as of_connection:
        writer_params = csv.writer(of_connection)
        writer_params.writerow([batch_size,model_type,n_layers,n_hidden,weight_decay,dropout,lr,eta_min,T0,T_mult,duration])
```

Comment: This just writes everything in one cell though. I want the time to be in a seperate cell so I can sort by time

Comment: It shouldn't write it into one cell. Each element of the list is a separate cell of the CSV.

Comment: I copied ypur answer and it still writes everything in one cell :/ I am really confused

Comment: I manged to get it working by adding the delimiter here: writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',') But now it always overwrites the one line. So after 15 iterations I only have 1 line in my csv

Comment: The `a` mode in the `open()` call should make it append to the file instead of overwriting.

Comment: Comma is the default delimiter, I don't know why you need to add that.

Comment: I am sorry of course I meant writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')